# Borrow problem in a BTreeMap of key-> HashSet

Tags: rust

I hit an issue while solving a [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/most-stones-removed-with-same-row-or-column/). Given an adjacency list under the form:

```rust
let mut adj: BTreeMap<(usize, usize), HashSet<(usize, usize)>> = BTreeMap::new();
```

Each vertex `(usize, usize)` represents the position of a stone on a grid. I am trying to remove a vertex. Given a *stone* = `(usize, usize)`, I need to get the `HashSet<(usize, usize)>` of its connected "neighbour" nodes, and then for each of these node, remove *stone* from their adjacency list:

```rust
let stone = adj.get(&(top.1, top.2)).unwrap();
for neighbour in stone.iter() {
    let adj_lst_neighbour = adj.get(neighbour).unwrap();
    adj_lst_neighbour.remove(&(top.1, top.2));
    //unwrap().remove(&(top.1,top.2));
}
```

No matter what I attempt with the above snippet, I am always stopped by the borrow checker and I do not understand why. There is no `iter_mut` method on `HashSet`, which does not help.

How shall I do it?

Here is the complete code:

```rust
use std::{
    borrow::BorrowMut,
    collections::{BTreeMap, BinaryHeap, HashSet},
};

struct Solution {}

impl Solution {
    pub fn remove_stones(stones: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> i32 {
        // Start CREATE ADJACENCY_LIST
        let mut adj: BTreeMap<(usize, usize), HashSet<(usize, usize)>> = BTreeMap::new();

        let mut stones = stones.clone();
        stones.sort();
        let mut idx = 0usize;
        while idx < stones.len() {
            let mut idx2 = idx + 1;
            while idx2 < stones.len() && stones[idx2][0] == stones[idx][0] {
                adj.entry((stones[idx][0] as usize, stones[idx][1] as usize))
                    .or_insert(HashSet::new())
                    .insert((stones[idx2][0] as usize, stones[idx2][1] as usize));
                adj.entry((stones[idx][0] as usize, stones[idx][1] as usize))
                    .or_insert(HashSet::new())
                    .insert((stones[idx2][0] as usize, stones[idx2][1] as usize));
                idx2 += 1;
            }
            idx = idx2;
        }

        stones.sort_unstable_by(|a, b| a[1].cmp(&b[1]));
        let mut idx = 0usize;
        while idx < stones.len() {
            let mut idx2 = idx + 1;
            while idx2 < stones.len() && stones[idx2][1] == stones[idx][1] {
                adj.entry((stones[idx][0] as usize, stones[idx][1] as usize))
                    .or_insert(HashSet::new())
                    .insert((stones[idx2][0] as usize, stones[idx2][1] as usize));
                adj.entry((stones[idx][0] as usize, stones[idx][1] as usize))
                    .or_insert(HashSet::new())
                    .insert((stones[idx2][0] as usize, stones[idx2][1] as usize));
                idx2 += 1;
            }
            idx = idx2;
        }

        // End CREATE ADJACENCY_LIST

        // Remove stones having non-zero but otherwise minimal number of edges
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        let mut heap: BinaryHeap<(i64, usize, usize)> = BinaryHeap::new();
        for (key, value) in adj.iter() {
            heap.push((-(value.len() as i64), key.0, key.1));
        }

        while heap.len() > 0 && heap.peek().unwrap().0 == 0 {
            heap.pop();
        }

        let mut counter: i32 = 0;
        while heap.len() > 0 {
            if heap.peek().unwrap().0 == 0 {
                heap.pop();
            }
            // do not update counter just remove isolated stone from the heap
            else {
                let top = heap.pop().unwrap();
                counter += 1;

                // we have removed this stone, we need to remove it from all neighbors adjacency lists
                // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                let stone = adj.get(&(top.1, top.2)).unwrap();
                for neighbour in stone.iter() {
                    let adj_lst_neighbour = adj.get(neighbour).unwrap();
                    adj_lst_neighbour.remove(&(top.1, top.2));
                    //unwrap().remove(&(top.1,top.2));
                }
            }
        }
        counter
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Whatever...");
}
```

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*adj_lst_neighbour` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:74:21
   |
73 |                     let adj_lst_neighbour = adj.get(neighbour).unwrap();
   |                         ----------------- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut HashSet<(usize, usize)>`
74 |                     adj_lst_neighbour.remove(&(top.1, top.2));
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `adj_lst_neighbour` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

Comment: I can tell you that your post is _far larger than it needs to be_ to express the problem. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: I think that formatting the code in the question is a good idea, as is addressing all the warnings provided by the compiler (yours has unfixed warnings). You should also include the error message, but I've done that for you.

Comment: The root problem is that there's no *compile-time guarantee* that your two calls to `adj.get` will not return the same value. If they did, then you'd have multiple references to the same value, one of which would want to be mutable. This is disallowed by the [rules of references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references).

Comment: But even if I add a `.clone()` at the end of the first `adj.get` line I have the same problem. Yet I should have copied the entire set?

Comment: [you also need to use `get_mut` to mutate the value](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=47106123de8d8e410a3edcee5d5652ed)

Comment: Thank you very much. So there is no way to avoid that copy (clone())? This is expensive...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235799/discussion-between-shepmaster-and-user2346536).